# Reading binary byte by byte in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

I'm currently trying to read a binary file in chunks, and my solution so far has been this:

```
first_portion = File.binread(replay_file, 20)
second_portion = File.binread(replay_file, 24, 20)
```

Where the first number is the amount of bytes to read and the second is the offset.

I know this is bad because File.binread closes the file each time after returning. How can I open the file once, do what I with with is, then close it when I'm done (but still use binread).

Also, another small question. I've been looking at a few examples of this in python and seen this:

```
UINT32 = 'uintle:32'

length = binary_file.read(UINT32)
content = binary_file.read(8 * length)
```

What exactly is this doing (how does it work), and what would this look like in Ruby?

Answer (score 5):

You can open the file and read bytes in chunks with [`#read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-read) and [`#seek`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-seek):

```
File.open(replay_file) do |file|
  first_portion = file.read(20)
  file.seek(24, IO::SEEK_END)
  second_portion = file.read(20)
end
```

The file is closed automatically in the `end`.

About the second question, I'm not a Python expert, and someone correct me if I'm wrong, but it would be this in Ruby:

```
length = binary_file.read(4).unpack('N').first
# 32 bits = 4 bytes
# i.e., read 4 bytes, convert to a 32 bit integer,
# fetch the first element of the array (unpack always returns an array)

content = binary_file.read(8 * length)
# pretty much verbatim
```

You can check more options here: [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-unpack)

Comment: Thanks, you've been incredibly helpful.

Comment: One quick question, how would that first line in the second answer change if I was dealing with UINT64 or FLOAT32? UINT64 would be 8 bytes, FLOAT32 would be 4 bytes, is that all that changes? Also, why is first necessary?

Comment: For FLOAT32 use `'g'`, and for UINT64 use `'Q>'`. I'm adding the link to `#unpack` in my answer for you to check.

Comment: It's possible that it's trying to read after the end of the file. For example: `"\x00\x00\x04\xD2".unpack('N')` returns `[1234]`, but `"".unpack('N')` returns `[nil]`. Can you show the string from both reads?

Comment: Yes, you can freely use the file inside other methods called inside the block. I just don't recommend saving it in an instance variable or the like. :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed your other question. `#unpack` always returns an array, so you need to get the `first` element of the array.

Comment: You can also use String#unpack1 instead of `.unpack(...).first`